# PHP how to cut a string between 2 symbols

Tags: php, string

I have this image name: `very-nice-rose-123-3.jpg`

How can I cut this into parts and receive only the part between last dash and the image extension. I need to get `3` in this example.

Comment: you can use `explode()`

Comment: anything shorter? without looping and etc?

Comment: you don't need to loop nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use string function, like `explode()`, `substr()`, etc.

```php
$file = explode('.', $file);
$file = explode('-', $file[0]);
echo end($file);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/234284)</kbd>

Or you could use regular expression:

```php
if (preg_match('~-?(\w+)\.\w+$~', $file, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/234329)</kbd>

Comment: Didn't think of regex for some reason. That would be the best way to handle this on my opinion.

Comment: Regex is almost certainly less efficient. `explode()` is probably the best way to do that. I'll do some profiling and come back.

Comment: your regex won't work if there is a string exists instead of number.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: it works for OP example, but I fixed the expression, to match any word characters.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is normally:

```
<?php

$num = strrev(
    explode(
        '-',
        strrev($filename),
        2
    )[0]
);
```

Docs for [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Through regex.

```
if (preg_match('~(?<=-)[^-.]+(?=\.[a-z]+$)~', $file, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

OR

```
if (preg_match('~-([^-.]+)\.[a-z]+$~', $file, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iC8wX6/5)